# Revolved vs. Revolves (reported speech)?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

If a sentence is past simple (record speech), and implies a constant fact. Would the fact be in present simple or past? 
Such as the following two sentences:

> - she told her students the Earth **revolves./revolved** around the Sun once a year.
> - She opined that San Francisco **had/has** the most beautiful views of any city in the United States.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it depends.
She told her students the Earth revolves around the Sun once a year. [it is a general idea, a scientific fact].

She told her students that the period was finished. [not a general proposition, finished action]

She opined that San Francisco has the most beautiful views of any US city. [a general proposition]

She opined that San Francisco had the most beautiful views of any US city until an earthquake destroyed it. [past event]